# Saving records to database Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I'm trying to save the data from the form. However, there is no record when I check the database side.

I'm using Laravel 10 and mySQL v5.7.

*** edit: I'm using azure mysql flexible server v5.7. I installed a mysql locally and it saved just fine. This might be an issue with azure. Thank you :) ***

**Controller **store()

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $personnelRegistry = null;
        $personnerlRegistryId = (int)$request->input('personnelRegistryId', null);

        if($personnerlRegistryId && $request->isMethod('post')){
            $personnelRegistry = PersonnelRegistry::find($personnerlRegistryId)->getAttributes();
            $joinDate = $request->get('joinDate');

                $personnel = new PersonnelDetail;
                $personnel->personnel_registry_id = $personnerlRegistryId;
                $personnel->service_id = $request->get('serviceId');
                $personnel->emp_status_id = (int)$request->get('employmentStatusId');
                $personnel->joining_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($joinDate));
                $personnel->ref_pos_id = (int)$request->get('posId');
                $personnel->step_id = (int)$request->get('stepId');
                $personnel->current_salary = 1;
                $personnel->is_current = (int)$request->get('isPersonnelCurrent');
                $personnel->created_by = 1;
                $personnel->updated_by = 1;

                $personnel->save();

            $request->session()->flash('status', 'Personnel details was created.');

            return redirect()->route('employee.show', ['employee' => $personnerlRegistryId]);
        } else {
           //Validation failed. Redirect
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PersonnelDetail extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'personnel_details';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    /**
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

}
```

**View**

```
                <form action="{{ route('employee.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Personnel Name</label>
                        
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">

                            <span id="personnelNamePlaceholder"></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="personnelRegistryId" id="personnelRegistryId" required />
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#searchPersonnel">Search Records</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Service Id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="serviceId" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Employee Status Id</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <select name="employmentStatusId" class="select2 form-control" id="employmentStatus">
                                <option label="&nbsp;"></option>
                                <option value="24">Permanent</option>
                                <option value="25">Contractual</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Join Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <input type="text" name="joinDate" class="form-control date-picker-close" id="joindate" value="{{ $date_now }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Position</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <select name="posId" class="form-control" id="positionId" require>
                                <option label="&nbsp;"></option>
                                @foreach($plantilla_items as $item)
                                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->uniq_item_no }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Step</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <select name="stepId" class="form-control" id="stepId" require>
                                <option label="&nbsp;"></option>
                                @foreach($steps as $step)
                                    <option value="{{ $step->id }}">{{ $step->description }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row">
                        <label class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Is Current?</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="isPersonnelCurrent" id="inlineRadio1" value="1" />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Yes</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="isPersonnelCurrent" id="inlineRadio2" value="0" />
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">No</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3 row mt-5">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10 ms-auto">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

No errors from laravel and it successfully redirects to the employee.show page.

Please and thank you..

I was expecting to have data in the database after save().

dd
[image]

Create Table personnel_details

```
CREATE TABLE `personnel_details` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `personnel_registry_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `service_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `org_code_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `position_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_status_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `joining_date` date NOT NULL,
  `leave_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ref_pos_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `step_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `is_current` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `current_salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKPersonnelRegistryTOPersonnelDetails_idx` (`personnel_registry_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKPersonnelRegistryTOPersonnelDDetails` FOREIGN KEY (`personnel_registry_id`) REFERENCES `personnel_registry` (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Create table personnel_registry

```
CREATE TABLE `personnel_registry` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `agency_emp_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `extension_name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  
 ...

  `created_by` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Is registry id exists in request data? Try to dump request attributes

Comment: yes lezhni. I added a screenshot of dd().

Comment: Why does your `dd` show the model name as `PersonnelDepedDetail`?

Comment: Forgot to remove the name of the agency I have project with.. For example sake.

Answer (score 0):

You must define fillable attributes On your Model.
Like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['personnel_registry_id', 'service_id'];
```

or define $guarded with empty property. but consider it's risk!

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

refer to document if you need more details

Comment: As all properties was set directly, the problem not in `$fillable`

Answer (score -1):

You're missing parentheses "()" mark on the model initiation. try this:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $personnelRegistry    = null;
    $personnerlRegistryId = (int)$request->input('personnelRegistryId');

    if($personnerlRegistryId && $request->isMethod('post')){
        $personnelRegistry = PersonnelRegistry::find($personnerlRegistryId)->getAttributes();
        $joinDate = $request->get('joinDate');

            $personnel                        = new PersonnelDetail();
            $personnel->personnel_registry_id = $personnerlRegistryId;
            $personnel->service_id            = $request->get('serviceId');
            $personnel->emp_status_id         = (int)$request->get('employmentStatusId');
            $personnel->joining_date          = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($joinDate));
            $personnel->ref_pos_id            = (int)$request->get('posId');
            $personnel->step_id               = (int)$request->get('stepId');
            $personnel->current_salary        = 1;
            $personnel->is_current            = (int)$request->get('isPersonnelCurrent');
            $personnel->created_by            = 1;
            $personnel->updated_by            = 1;

            $personnel->save();

        $request->session()->flash('status', 'Personnel details was created.');

        return redirect()->route('employee.show', ['employee' => $personnerlRegistryId]);
    } else {
       //Validation failed. Redirect
    }
}
```

the different thing is :

```
$personnel = new PersonnelDetail;
```

I changed it to :

```
$personnel = new PersonnelDetail();
```

In Laravel, when you want to instantiate a model within a controller, you need to use parentheses () after the model name because it represents a method call. The model name followed by parentheses indicates that you are calling the constructor of the model class to create a new instance of that model.

By including the parentheses, you are invoking the constructor method, which is responsible for setting up the initial state of the model object and preparing it for use. It allows you to create a new instance of the model class and access its properties and methods within your controller.

Comment: thanks. I've tried adding parenthesis but no avail. I noticed the id is incrementing every time I try to dd() $personnel var.

Comment: This is not accurate. When there are no required parameters, the parentheses are optional when newing up a new instance (though recommended by code guidelines). This is pure PHP and has nothing to do with Laravel. From the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php): "If there are no arguments to be passed to the class's constructor, parentheses after the class name may be omitted."

Comment: @patricus that's new to me, thanks, man

Comment: @dualinline where'd you put your dd? if it's after the save() method, it's possible that the record has been saved

Comment: For this screenshot. It's after the $personnel->save(). 

I did a select query on the database but there was no record.. My autocommit parameter is true..

Comment: @dualinline have you tried looking at the database directly? like using a dbms?

Comment: Yes @YusufGiovanno, I am sure that my db is connected for I was able to select the personnel_id from another table. I am using mysql Workbench.

Comment: how about you give us your DDL of those 2 table, and maybe with 1 dummy data for the personnel registry so we can try it. and hopefully find the solution

Comment: I've edited my post. Added create tables.. It's weird that the auto increment value is increasing but there are no records in the personnel_details table. thanks!

Comment: And according to PSR `()` is required on object creating